# Table Joints on MySQL with collation "utf8_general_ci" error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, coldfusion

I have 2 tables. `Table1` contains a profile. `Table2` contains user login details. The two tables are related by the same column: `gurdianID`. I want to get a single row from 'Table1' and 'Table2' where the 'gurdianID' matches in both the tables. i.e. Example `gurdianID'='15001'`.

I tried the following but it keeps giving me a MySQL error:

```
SELECT *
FROM  portalGurdian, gurdLogin
WHERE portalGurdian.guardID=gurdLogin.guardID
AND   portalGurdian.guardID='15001';
```

The Error Message is:

```
MySQL said: Documentation
#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
```

Any guidance on how to resolve this ?

Comment: Just looking at the error, the problem sounds pretty self explanatory. Did you search first? A quick search turned up some promising threads/solutions. For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285207/mysql-error-code-1267-illegal-mix-of-collations-latin1-general-cs-implicit

Comment: (Edit) Never mind, I see you figured it out already. *RE: Lesson Learned: Read the error message carefully ...*  Haha, yep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a search on the **MySQL Error code** and found that the **collations** were slightly different, and causing the issue.

I went ahead and made sure both the tables had the same collation ... i.e. **'utf8_general_ci'**

Lesson Learned: Read the error message carefully ...